# jQuery: Prevent adding on('click') twice

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a page that is used as an asynchronously loaded tab, and as a dialog. It has a button on it which I have given an event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on('click', '#my-id-name', function () {
         // do stuff;
      });
   });
</script>
```

Problem is that the content of this tab/dialog gets refreshed multiple times, which means that the above script is run again, and the events are duplicated. The result is that when the item is clicked, the event is called multiple times.

Is there some way to prevent duplicate events, or to remove existing events added to document using the `.on(...)` method? I cannot remove all click events on the document, and I need to be listening on the document level.

PS: I'm working in MVC 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).off('click', '#my-id-name')
```